# What happens to the services that do not have a killing-script in the new run level?

Tags: services, daemon, sysvinit, runlevel

I read, that each runlevel has its own set of services or daemons, which can be looked up in `/etc/rcX.d` (X for the respect runlevel), there are scripts which names start with `S` and start services of the runlevel, there are also scripts that starts with a `K`, they are killing-scripts to stop a service from running.

Now, my question points to the fact, that it is possible to enter each runlevel from each other runlevels (2-5). for instance one can enter runlevel 1 from runlevel 2,3,4 or 5. Since each of them have different sets of services, why there is only one set of killing scripts? When I compare `/etc/rc1.d` and `/etc/rc5.d`  there are services in runlevel 5 for which no killing script exist in runlevel 1. What happens to theese services when transiting runlevels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are thinking of this in an incorrect way; the K scripts which are present for instance in runlevel 3 are not meant to be for killing stuff before entering runlevel 3, but when exiting runlevel 3 before entering some other.

So transitioning from runlevel 5 to runlevel 1 would first execute the `K`ill scripts in `/etc/rc5.d` (which would match the `S`tart scripts executed when entering there) then the `S`tart scripts in `/etc/rc1.d`